# Unknown table in field list (MySQL in vb.net)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I use MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand and MySqlConnection

```
Public fillGridCmdTxt As String = "SELECT tblItems.part_num AS Part#, tblCategory.category_description AS Category, " _
            & " tblItems.item_name AS 'Item Name', tblItems.item_desc AS Description, " _
            & "tblItems.item_qty AS Qty, tblUnit.unit_name AS Unit, tblItems.item_price AS 'Selling Price(Php)' " _
            & "FROM tblUnit INNER JOIN tblItems ON tblUnit.unit_id = tblItems.unit_id INNER JOIN tblCategory " _
            & "ON tblItems.category_id = tblCategory.category_id "
```

and when i use executeNonQuery
on MySqlCommand, it gives me an error...
It says that "**Unkown table '**tblItems*** in field list*" even the table is really existing on my database... a little help please?

Comment: Some Operative Systems are case sensitive. Have you double checked this?

Comment: Check that your database-connection is connected to the right database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose `Part#` between quotes.

The `#` sign starts a comment in MySQL, so your whole statement is read as just `SELECT tblItems.part_num AS Part`. The error message tells you that you are naming a table in the fields list that you didn't specify in the `FROM` list (because the `FROM` list got commented out).